# Exogenous variables SARIMAX

Tags: time-series, arima, autoregressive, seasonality, moving-average

I am trying to model some data as a time series analysis, and I have one exogenous variable that I have reason to believe should have a significant effect on the response. but when I include the variable when fitting my SARIMAX model using statsmodels.api the predicted responses are almost identical to when I fit without the variable when I use n-step ahead prediction. I was wondering if there might be some common explanations for this sort of behavior, perhaps the exogenous variable should be scaled or something along those lines.

I am somewhat new to time series analysis so if possible it would be helpful to include with any answer documentation/sources.

Thanks